# UWP app run after deploy from package - crash

Tags: c#, xaml, crash, uwp, windows-10-universal

I created big update for my uwp app(Windows 10 desktop). My debug and release configuration app runing on my PC. I created package for store. I deploy test folder app(MyApp_VersionNumber_Test) on other PC - the deployment is successful. But I running my app then app crashing. It is log  from windows event:

```
  Faulting application name: myApp.exe, version: 1.2.1.0, time stamp: 0x580c6e57
  Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.14393.187, time stamp: 0x57cf9d04
  Exception code: 0xc000027b
  Fault offset: 0x000000000055bac8
  Faulting process id: 0x1fec
  Faulting application start time: 0x01d22d08a5b94ce7
  Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MyPackage\MyApp.exe
  Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
  Report Id: 38924ba1-d61f-4efd-ac28-5ba06af4658d
  Faulting package full name: MyPAckage
  Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

I enabled user mode dump, but my dump folder is empty. I used application insights(in my uwp app) but logs is empty. Any ideas? Problem is with xaml. How do I find this bug?

Comment: Have you tried in some other devices? Do they have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I published test folder on three pc, and I got this problem on all pc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this  problem. I had two ways to search for solutions. I write them here, I hope it will help to save time.

1. Start with the end. I have the exception code, it's `0xc000027b` (as seen in the Windows Event Viewer). These articles show how to use the dump to fix errors in the windows store app:

   [Debugging a Windows 8.1 Store App Crash Dump](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2014/01/13/debugging-a-windows-8-1-store-app-crash-dump/)

   [Understanding and resolving failures in Windows Store apps](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/01/20/understanding-and-resolving-failures-in-windows-store-apps/#lMBLJU1DpkXHXxGc.99)
2. I decided to look for the problem in the source code.
   I opened exception list in Visual studio(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>).
   I selected all exceptions for "Common Language Runtime",
   ran in Debug mode. Then the error was found:

   ```
    var res = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString(key);
   ```

I changed my code to:

```
    LocalizedResources = new ResourceLoader();
    var res = LocalizedResources.GetString(key);
```